# How to upgrade from ASP.NET MVC Core 2.1 to ASP.NET MVC Core 6?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1, asp.net-core-6.0

I have developed an ASP.NET MVC Core 2.1 Project, and Now I want to Upgrade it to ASP.NET MVC Core 6, So I have posted here my existing Startup Code, Program Class Code, and the NuGet Packages Code, version 2.1, Please help me to modify all my existing code from asp.net core 2.1 to asp.net core 6 thank you in advance.

Here are my **csproj** NuGet Packages that Need to modify to ASP.net Core 6

```xml
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
        <NoWin32Manifest>true</NoWin32Manifest>
        <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
        <MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>true</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>
        <UserSecretsId>*******************</UserSecretsId>
        <ServerGarbageCollection>false</ServerGarbageCollection>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="BCrypt-Core" Version="2.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="ClosedXML" Version="0.97.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Magick.NET-Q16-AnyCPU" Version="7.8.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.1.7" />
        <PackageReference Include="microsoft.aspnetcore.app" Version="2.1.4" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.1.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="2.1.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.1.14" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.1.14" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.1.14">
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
        </PackageReference>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="2.1.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="2.1.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="2.1.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.1.10" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="5.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.Linq.Dynamic.Core" Version="1.2.7" />
    </ItemGroup>


</Project>
```

Here is my Startup Code asp.net core 2.1 that need to modify to asp.net core 6

```
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBconnection");
            services.AddDbContext<HoshmandDBContext>(option => option.UseSqlServer(connection));
            services.AddAuthentication(option =>
            {
                option.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                option.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                option.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = "/Logins/UserLogin/";
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/AccessDenied";
                options.Cookie.Expiration = new TimeSpan(10,00,00);
            });

            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(2);
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;

            });
            
            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(option =>
            {
                option.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(540);
            });

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("HasAccess", policy => policy.AddRequirements(new HasAccessRequirment()));
            });
 
            services.AddTransient<IAuthorizationHandler, HasAccessHandler>();
            services.AddTransient<IMvcControllerDiscovery, MvcControllerDiscovery>();

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();
            app.UseSession();
            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                   template: "{controller=UserProfiles}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
```

Here is My Program Cs Code asp.net core 2.1 need to modify to asp.net core 6

```
    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }
        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args)
        {
            return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseStartup<Startup>();
        }
    }
```

Here is an Example of my Home Page Controller asp.net mvc 2.1 need to modify to asp.net 6

```
    [DisplayName("Dashboard")]
    [Authorize(policy: "HasAccess")]
    public class HomeController : BaseController
    {
        private readonly IMvcControllerDiscovery _mvcControllerDiscovery;

        private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;
        public HomeController(HoshmandDBContext context, IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment) : base(context)
        {
            _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
        }
        public IActionResult Index(DateTime? date = null)
        {
            date = date ?? GetLocalDateTime();
            ViewBag.date = date;
        }
    }
```

Here is my Login Controller Code Asp.net core 2.1 need to modify to asp.net core 6

```
    public class LoginsController : BaseController
    {
        public LoginsController(HoshmandDBContext context) : base(context)
        {
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UserLogin()
        {
            return await Task.Run(() => View(new Login()));
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should refer the [Migrate document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/21-to-22?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) to step by step update an existing ASP.NET Core 2.1 project to ASP.NET Core 6.0, like this: 2.1 to 3.0 => 3.0 to 3.1 => 3.1 to 5.0 => 5.0 to 6.0, Please refer to this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have developed an ASP.NET MVC Core 2.1 Project, and Now I want to
> Upgrade it to ASP.NET MVC Core 6, So I have posted here my existing
> Startup Code, Program Class Code, and the NuGet Packages Code, version
> 2.1, Please help me to modify all my existing code from asp.net core 2.1 to asp.net core 6

Well, your question requires too elaborative explanation to answer as it has large context to implement. In addition, you haven't shared all relevant references so I am considering only the basic Migration Essentials from 2.1 to 6. Let's begin:

**Startup.cs To Program.cs:**

As you already know, Asp.net Core 6 has no startup.cs file as it only has `program.cs` file. It should looks like below:

[image]

So while migrating to Asp.net Core 6 we should implement `Startup` and `ConfigureServices` as below:

```cs
using Dotnet6MVC.Data;
using Dotnet6MVC.IRepository;
using Dotnet6MVC.Repository;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;

using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;


var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);


var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<HoshmandDBContext>(x => x.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

//Authentication
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(option =>
{
    option.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    option.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    option.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = "/Logins/UserLogin/";
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/AccessDenied";
           options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(2);
        });

builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(2);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;

});

builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(option =>
{
    option.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(540);
});

//builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
//{
//    options.AddPolicy("HasAccess", policy => policy.AddRequirements(new HasAccessRequirment()));
//});

//builder.Services.AddTransient<IAuthorizationHandler, HasAccessHandler>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IMvcControllerDiscovery, MvcControllerDiscovery>();
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddMvc();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseCookiePolicy();
app.UseSession();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=UserProfiles}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.Run();
```

**Note:**
Here in `program.cs` files you should consider below changes:

1. Use `options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(2)` instead of `options.Cookie.Expiration = new TimeSpan(10,00,00)`
2. Use `builder.Services.AddAuthentication` Instead of `services.AddAuthentication` likewise other service as well.
3. Use `builder.Services.AddMvc()` Instead of `services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion`
4. Use `app.MapControllerRoute(` Instead of `app.UseMvc(routes =>`

In addition, as you haven't shared `HasAccessRequirment` details so I haven't explain it. You can ask a separate question for that once you encounter any issue on it.

**DbContext:**

It will be almost same. I am using this pattern of "Database First" thus you can modify as per your requirement and preference of other pattern like "code first". [You can check here for more details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-6.0#create-the-database-context)

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Dotnet6MVC.Models;
namespace Dotnet6MVC.Data
{
    public class HoshmandDBContext: DbContext
    {
        public HoshmandDBContext(DbContextOptions<HoshmandDBContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }
        public DbSet<Users> Users { get; set; }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
           
            modelBuilder.Entity<Users>().ToTable("Users");
           

        }
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```cs
using Dotnet6MVC.IRepository;
using Dotnet6MVC.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Dotnet6MVC.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
        private readonly IMvcControllerDiscovery _mvcControllerDiscovery;
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IMvcControllerDiscovery mvcControllerDiscovery, IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _mvcControllerDiscovery = mvcControllerDiscovery;  
            _hostingEnvironment = webHostEnvironment;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
         
         
            var getLocalDate = _mvcControllerDiscovery.GetLocalDate();
            ViewBag.date = getLocalDate;
            return View();
        }

       


        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** In 2.1 we used `IHostingEnvironment` for working with files. Moreover, in Asp.net Core 6 it has changed to `IWebHostEnvironment` so bear in mind. Another point `middleware` or `actionFilter` like `[DisplayName("Dashboard")] [Authorize(policy: "HasAccess")]` remain same as you can register as `app.UseMiddleware<AutoTimerMiddleware>()` in `program.cs` file. [You can refer here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

**Test User Profile Controller:**

```
public class UserProfilesController : Controller
    {
        private readonly HoshmandDBContext _context;
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _environment;


        public UserProfilesController(IWebHostEnvironment environment, HoshmandDBContext context)
        {
            _environment = environment;
            _context = context;
        }
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            return View(await _context.Users.Where(u=>u.UserId==10).ToListAsync());
        }
    }
```

**Cspros File:**
Here I have seen your `cspros` has lot of reference which not shared accordingly. So I have explained only the mandatory migration related reference.

[image]

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <RazorCompileOnPublish>false</RazorCompileOnPublish>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="6.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**Note:**  Please note that, you should download `EntityFrameworkCore.Relational` and `EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` from Nuget package manager in order to basic migration.

**Output:**

[image]

**Important :**

1. One simple but crucial tips, anything related to `ConfigureServices` in 2.1 must be placed above `var app = builder.Build()` of Asp.net Core 6 `program.cs` file and
2. Anything inside  `public void Configure` of 2.1 must be placed above `app.Run()` or we can say after `var app = builder.Build()`.

Comment: Dear Mr. Farid Uddin Kiron, thank you very much for your effort to giving nice explanation about my question, this is a large project implemented in a hospital, that's way I didn't share all the details to avoid long content. I am very excited to implement your solution and migrate my project to .net6, I will create a new project in .net6 then apply all the modifications as you mentioned, if I done it successfully will reply here and mark your answer as the best solution. @MdFaridUddinKiron

Comment: Sure, let me know how its going on.

Comment: Dear  Mr. Farid Uddin Kiron
I have migrated my project but got a lot of errors, I have added a **New Section Added After Migrating from asp.net core 2.1 to.Net6** in my question, please have a look at the new section of my question and kindly provide your solution, thank you @MdFaridUddinKiron

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As I told you before, its a migration related question, all problem cannot be answered in one question. You probably, didn't focus into my suggestion. Don't migrate all the stuff together, do it partially, transfer one part, then build and run, then move to next part. Your current part is not related to formar concern. Please ask new question for each of your new issue. Only I can asist you then, hope you got my concern. No the migration question has been resolved in one go.

Comment: Thank you, dear Mr.Farid , I got your answer and migrated step by step, now and solve most of those error, but the big error is with the authorization I will post a new question
@MdFaridUddinKiron

Comment: Thanks for your reply, sure, I would love to assist you further on this.

Comment: Dear @MdFaridUddinKiron Please have a look at my new question regarding migrating from asp.net core 2.1 to.NET6

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74683781/how-to-handle-authorization-error-after-migrated-from-asp-net-core-2-1-to-net-6]

Comment: Suree, I will check if I could assist on that.