# How to handle authorization error after migrated from ASP.NET Core 2.1 to .NET 6?

Tags: authorization, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-2.1

I have migrated my project from asp.net core 2.1 to .NET 6, and now I am facing an error with
`context.Resource as AuthorizationFilterContext` which is return NULL.

I have implemented a custom Policy-based Authentication using AuthorizationFilterContext,  It seems that.NET 6 do not support `AuthorizationFilterContext` Please help me how to modify the below code from asp.net core 2.1 to .NET6. thank you.

Here is the error message in this line `var mvcContext = context.Resource as AuthorizationFilterContext;`

> **mvcContext == NULL**
> [image]

Here is the Implemention Code of `AuthorizationHandler` and `AuthorizationHandlerContext`

```
public class HasAccessRequirment : IAuthorizationRequirement { }
    public class HasAccessHandler : AuthorizationHandler<HasAccessRequirment>
    {
        public readonly HoshmandDBContext _context;
        public HasAccessHandler(HoshmandDBContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, HasAccessRequirment requirement)
        {
            Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<Task>() != null);
            List<int?> userGroupIds = new List<int?>();
            // receive the function informations

            var mvcContext = context.Resource as AuthorizationFilterContext;
            if ((mvcContext != null) && !context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                mvcContext.Result = new RedirectToActionResult("UserLogin", "Logins", null);
                return Task.FromResult(Type.Missing);
            }
            if (!(mvcContext?.ActionDescriptor is ControllerActionDescriptor descriptor))
            {
                return Task.FromResult(Type.Missing);
            }
            var currntActionAddress = descriptor.ControllerName + "/" + descriptor.ActionName;
            // finding all information about controller and method from Tables 
            // check user has access to current action which is being called
            //allActionInfo = ListAcctionsFromDatabase;
            //bool isPostBack = allActionInfo.FirstOrDefault(a => a.action == currntActionAddress)?.IsMenu ?? true;
            bool isPostBack = false;
            if (!isPostBack)
            {
                mvcContext.Result = new RedirectToActionResult("AccessDenied", descriptor.ControllerName, null);
                context.Succeed(requirement);
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
            else
            {
                mvcContext.Result = new RedirectToActionResult("AccessDeniedView", descriptor.ControllerName, null);
                context.Succeed(requirement);
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }

        }
    }
```

Here is my Program.cs Code:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("HasAccess", policy => policy.AddRequirements(new HasAccessRequirment()));
});

builder.Services.AddTransient<IAuthorizationHandler, HasAccessHandler>();
```

Here is the Controller Code:

```
   [Authorize(policy: "HasAccess")]
    public class HomeController : BaseController
    {
    }
```

Comment: please have a look to this question @MdFaridUddinKiron

Comment: Could you please show us the structure of your `AccessDenied` page?

Comment: As I checked the issue is here `if (!(mvcContext?.ActionDescriptor is ControllerActionDescriptor descriptor))`  the Controller Name and Action name is NULL in .net6,  but in .net2.1 it is not NULL @MdFaridUddinKiron

Comment: Issue is not complex, but your code is not reproducible because you paste all the code even those are not relavent or exact deepended code has not shared, by the way, are you using identity for authentication?

Comment: No, I am have not used built Identity I write, custom authentication @MdFaridUddinKiron

Comment: The mvcContext Value is NULL in.NET6 
`var mvcContext = context.Resource as AuthorizationFilterContext;`

but in .net 2.1 this is not NULL, it returns 
**mvcContext = {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.AuthorizationFilterContext}**
@MdFaridUddinKiron

Comment: I am checking unfortunately, cannot successfully load the project bacause of other dependent code.

Comment: Please remove other codes only check this var mvcContext = context.Resource as AuthorizationFilterContext; why it is null, I think the issue is here that mvcContext  is NULL @MdFaridUddinKiron

Comment: Okay sure, let me investigate further.

Comment: I have added the Screenshot of both .net core 2.1 and .NET 6 at bottom of  my question, please see those screenshots you will find what is the exact error @MdFaridUddinKiron

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250184/discussion-between-hedayat-hoshmand-and-md-farid-uddin-kiron).

Answer (score 1):

There are some changes since .net core 3 about AuthorizationFilterContext:
A. MVC is no longer add AuthorizeFilter to ActionDescriptor and ResourceInvoker won’t call AuthorizeAsync().
B. It will add Filter as metadata to endpoint. Also, in .net 5 it changed the **context.Resource** as the type of DefaultHttpContext.

So here is the new method:

```
public class MyAuthorizationPolicyHandler : AuthorizationHandler<OperationAuthorizationRequirement>
{

    public MyAuthorizationPolicyHandler()
    {
    }

    protected async override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, OperationAuthorizationRequirement requirement)
    {
        var result = false;

        if (context.Resource is Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.DefaultHttpContext httpContext)
        {
            var endPoint = httpContext.GetEndpoint();
            if (endPoint != null)
            {
                var attributeClaims = endPoint.Metadata.OfType<MyAuthorizeAttribute>()
                //TODO: Add your logic here
            }

            if (result)
            {
                context.Succeed(requirement);
            }
        }
    }
```

Please refer to this discussion: ["context.Resource as AuthorizationFilterContext" returning null in ASP.NET Core 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59197631/context-resource-as-authorizationfiltercontext-returning-null-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: I have  the screenshot of the error at bottom of my question,  please have a look at that, and guide what part of my code I need to change @XiaotianYang

Comment: In fact, I can't know your goal of using `if((mvcContext?.ActionDescriptorisControllerActionDescriptor descriptor))` So please try commenting this part and see if it works.

Comment: I am using a custom authorization, so all that I need to get AuthorizationFilterContext in .NET 6 the error is that AuthorizationFilterContext is return a NULL value for example below code is return NULL,  mvcContext  in asp.net core 2.1  this is not null it's null in .NET6 only 
`var mvcContext = context.Resource as AuthorizationFilterContext;  `
@XiaotianYang

Comment: this code does not work for .NET6